# .on function not being fired

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to use the .on event when some text is clicked. Here is my fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/zyUkd/73/

But nothing is being fired when I click 'link', I don't know why ? From reading http://api.jquery.com/on/ I don't think the data I should be passing is .connected ?

This needs to work for dynamically added elements.
Here is the code from the fiddle :

```
<div id="myID">
    <a class="connected" >link</a>
</div>

​$(function() {

$(".connected").on('click', '.connected', function() {
    alert('fired)'
        $(".connected").append("<a>hello</a>");
});



});

​.connected {
    float: left;
    margin: 6px;
}
```

Comment: I hate jQuery!!!! Use MooTools... www.mootools.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either this:

```
$(".connected").on('click', function() {
    alert('fired')
    $(".connected").append("<a>hello</a>");
});​
```

Or this:

```
$("#myID").on('click', '.connected', function() {
    alert('fired')
    $(".connected").append("<a>hello</a>");
});​
```

Note, the second variant works for dynamically added elements.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zyUkd/74/

Comment: the second variant is what I'm looking for. I don't have a div id, just the .css class . Does this mean I need to add an id the <a> element ? I've updated my question

Comment: @user470184 No, instead of `#myID` you can use *any* parent element of `.connected` (even `body` or `document`).

Comment: brilliant thanks! if not too much trouble can you elaborate on why this works ?

Comment: There was a [good answer](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) for that. *jQuery scans the document for $('#myID'), and binds the alert function along with the click event and '.connected' CSS selector as parameters. Any time an event bubbles up to $('#myID'), it checks to see if the event was a click and if the target element of that event matches the CSS selector. If both checks are true, it executes the function.*

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the seccond `.connected`. also your alert is written wrong.

```
$(function(){
        $(".connected").on('click', function() {
            alert('fired');
            $(".connected").append("<a>hello</a>");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a ready function, as well as fixed a syntax error on alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/zyUkd/75/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".connected").on('click', function() {
            alert('fired');
                $(".connected").append("<a>hello</a>");
        });    

 });
```

​

Comment: Include the code in your answer, don't just link to a fiddle.